# Why does my c# Windows Service not trust the connection to my testing server?

Tags: c#, windows, ssl, service, webapi

I am writing a Windows service to call a web API that I have previously written. Both are written in C#, targeting .NET 4.8, and the Windows service uses System.Net.WebClient to make calls to the web API.

I have successfully published my API to IIS on our testing server. IIS is set up to only accept HTTPS connections. Because our testing server is internal facing only and cannot be reached from the Internet, I have generated a self-signed certificate from IIS and have loaded it into the Trusted Certificate store on my development machine.

I am unable to get an SSL certificate from an external CA or use LetsEncrypt as the testing server cannot be reached from the outside world (that's not an option).

With the self-signed certificate in place, I can open a browser on my dev machine, and successfully connect to and retrieve data my Web API without any "not trusted" warnings, so the self-signed certificate appears to be working correctly.

I initially wrote and tested my Windows service code in a WinForms app to make sure everything is working correctly, before porting it to a service. When the code runs in an app on my dev machine, it can connect to the API on our testing server (using HTTPS).

I copied the exact same code to a Windows Service, and when that service is built, installed and started on my dev machine, it throws the exception "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel".

It appears that the service is not honoring the certificate in the Trusted Certificate store on my dev machine. I know the certificates are being honored by browsers, because when I remove it, the browser warns me about the web site not being secure. When I reinstall the certificate, the browser warning goes away.

I was expecting that the same self-signed certificate which allowed a browser to trust the server would allow my windows service to trust the server.

So, to sum up, I can reach my Web API running on our testing server from my dev machine via a browser (and HTTPS) without errors. I can reach the same API using code that is running in a desktop application. But as soon as that exact same code is in a Windows Service and installed on my dev machine, System.Net.WebClient suddenly has trust issues.

Do Windows Services have a different trust model or run with different privilege levels that I need to take into consideration? Or have I completely misunderstood certificates?

For what it's worth, the calling code is:

```
  public class RequestHandler
    {
        private String URL { get; set; }
        private WebClient Client { get; set; }

        public RequestHandler(String url)
        {
            URL = url;
            Client = new WebClient();
            Client.Headers.Add(Constants.UserAgent, Constants.UserAgentValue);
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        }


        public String GetData()
        {
            try
            {
                var response = Client.DownloadString(URL);
                return (response);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LogEvent(EventLogEntryType.Error, e.Message);
                return (String.Empty);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Which user your service runs under? It may happen that CA for the self signed cert is imported for your user but not for other users (e.g. NETWORK_SERVICE)

Comment: "With the self-signed certificate in place" - in *what* place?

Comment: There are multiple cert stores on your machine, one for your user, and one for the machine (i.e., any user running from your machine). If your service is running as, say `network service`, then it's not going to use your cert store